# How to use return two time in a function in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, async-await, django-views

I have a model called response. If the user is selected for a duration the response is turning to the default value after that duration time. But I need to return the value until the duration time is over. I think I need to use the async function. I looked at the SO. but couldn't find any solutioın.

models.py

```
class Response(models.Model):
    def_res = models.CharField()
    expected_res = models.CharField()
    current_res = models.CharField()
    is_duration= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

views.py

```
def manage_response(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        a = Response.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get('resp_id'))
        a.current_res = a.expected_res 
        a.save()
        if not a.is_duration == True:
            return JsonResponse(a.current_res)
        else:
            return JsonResponse(a.expected_res )
            #after return won't work in sync 
            time.sleep(a.duration)
            a.current_res = a.def_res
            a.save()
            return JsonResponse(a.current_res)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dictionary` when passing through `JsonResponse`.

```
#here
def return_response(res):
    return JsonResponse(res)


def manage_response(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        a = Response.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get('resp_id'))
        a.current_res = a.expected_res 
        a.save()
        if not a.is_duration == True:
            return JsonResponse(a.current_res)
        else:
            return_response(a.expected_res)
            #after return won't work in sync 
            time.sleep(a.duration)
            a.current_res = a.def_res
            a.save()
            return JsonResponse(a.current_res)
```

Comment: I want to return data to the user and I want to return the updated data again the second time after the duration that the user sent.


Example:
   User click on the button return response is --> Yes.
   After the duration that the user sent return response is --> No.